# Using a loop to create new columns in dataframe with the same pattern

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'd like to create new columns in a dataframe in which I produce yearly data
The variables I have are:

```
id_net_profit_20M05
id_op_income_20M05
```

This is how the dataset looks like:

```
company  ip_net_profit_20M05  ip_op_income_20M05 ip_pl_bef_tax

 x            121                     185              129
 y            145                     87               175
```

and I want to create annualised variables with different accounting year:

```
id_net_profit_Y_20M05 <- id_net_profit_20M05*12/5
id_op_income_Y_20M05 <- id_op_income_20M05*12/5
```

A loop would do the work for all the variables I have, but the ones below is not working:

```
variables<-c("id_net_profit", "id_op_income")
for (v in variables){
  DF$paste0(v,"_20M05_Y",sep="")<- DF$paste0(v,"_20M05",sep="")*12/5
}
```

Do you know why?

Many thanks

Comment: please add some data e.g. a snippet of input and output dataframe

Comment: I added some data that might be representative of my dataset

Comment: What is the output that you would expect? Can you add an example of what the desired output would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute the line of code in your `for` with the following:

```
DF[paste0(v,"_20M05_Y",sep="")] <- DF[paste0(v,"_20M05",sep="")]*12/5
```

You cannot access to a column of `DF` using simply `DF$paste0(...)`

I post for you this additional example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = rnorm(10))
DF$paste0("var", 1) # here you get an error
DF[paste0("var", 1)] # here you don't get an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data.frame is called `df` with following format:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ company            : chr  "x" "y"
$ ip_net_profit_20M05: num  121 145
$ ip_op_income_20M05 : num  185 87
$ ip_pl_bef_tax      : num  129 175
```

then you can try

```
variables<- names(df)[2:3]
for (i in variables){
    df[,paste0(i,"_20M05_Y",sep="")] <- df[,i]*12/5
}
df
company ip_net_profit_20M05 ip_op_income_20M05 ip_pl_bef_tax ip_net_profit_20M05_20M05_Y ip_op_income_20M05_20M05_Y
1       x                 121                185           129                       290.4                      444.0
2       y                 145                 87           175                       348.0                      208.8
```

Or use an alternative tidyverse way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(2,3), list(`20M05_Y` = ~.*12/5), .names="{col}_{fn}")
```